# Nodal analysis for dependent voltage source

Tags: nodal-analysis

[image]

I want to apply nodal analysis at the red marked node of the above circuit.  Here is my equation :

$$0.2v_0 - i_0 - 5 + \frac{v_3}{40} + \frac{v_3 - v_2}{10} = 0$$

My equation includes a supernode formed due to the dependent voltage source $$4v_0$$

**Is my equation correct for nodal analysis?**

Comment: I don't see how your equation is sufficient to solve everything. Are you ***only*** trying to provide a nodal equation for a single node and that is all? (You may also need to label your nodes before anyone can try and make sense of your equation.)

Comment: @jonk...  Updated the question...and yes, I am asking for this specific node only..

Comment: The equation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation matches your circuit.

To make it a canonical nodal equation for use in nodal analysis, you should express \$v_0\$ and \$i_0\$ in terms of node voltages (\$v_1\$, \$v_2\$ and \$v_3\$).